# Conditional Formatting using dates and weekends

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have data in a spreadsheet like this

```
Name  | 9/1/2016 | 9/2/2016 | .... | 6/8/2017
Abe   |          |          |      |
Jonas |          |          |      |
```

I want to highlight every column where the date is either a weekend or a user defined date (for instance, a holiday....does excel already know federal holidays?).

The conditional format I have is:
Applies to 
=$b$2:$KI$62

Format values where the following formula is true

```
#1 =WEEKDAY($B$1:$KI$1,1)=1 
#2 =WEEKDAY($B$1:$KI$1,1)=7
```

Yet nothing shows up. At the best I've been able to only make the bottom row show up through playing with the function. Why?

Comment: Please read about the [WORKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33) and implementing a list of holidays. (note **WORKDAY** not **WEEKDAY**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Name** in A1, select B2 to the extents of your data and use the following to create a conditional formatting rule.

```
=WORKDAY(B$1-1, 1, $L$2:$L$4)<>B$1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. So its formatting the entire sheet (applies to cell b2:ki62) and i am using that formula

Comment: See if [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/CFR_Weekends_Holidays.xlsb) helps.

Comment: Hi. It does somewhat. I didn't use that comparison; I found that the <> or the = comparison was making them either all true or all false (thus no comparison).  So what I did was use the workday function (which returns a date), and subtract it from the value in the first row. If the result from that is greater than 0, apply the formatting.

So it's here:

'=WORKDAY(B$1-1,1,Holidays)-B$1>0'

Applies to cells:
'$b$2:$KI$62'